# How to add multiple objects in a cell?

Tags: javascript, gridjs

Hope you are doing great!.

I have to insert multiple records in the same cell using gridjs. Can someone help me with that?

Let's say here is my sample response from my api

```
{"results": [{"Program": "Sample Program", "Show": "Sample Show Hello", "Edition": 
"Edition Name", "Venue": "Venue Name", "Start_Time": "Start Time", "End_Time": "End 
Time", "Partner": "Partner", "Artist": ["Artist 1", "Artist 2"]}]}
```

As you can see I have multiple artists.
Now here is my Grid code

```
var x = new gridjs.Grid({
  columns: ["Program","Show","Edition", "Venue", "Start Time","End Time","Partner","Artist"],
  pagination: {
    limit: 4
  },
  search: true,
  sort: true,
  server:{
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8003/1/',
    then: data => data.results.map(show => 
      [show.Program, show.Show, show.Edition,show.Venue,show.Start_Time,show.End_Time,show.Partner,show.Artist]
    )
  },
}).render(document.getElementById("wrapper"));
```

and the grid displays artist 1 and artist 2 in the same column. Please see the reference image.

[image: Image reference]

In my cell I need output like Artist 1 
 Artist 2

I would really appreciate any leads!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tack a `.toString()` on the end of `show.Artist` and it will turn the array into a comma-delimited string. Do `.toString().replace(',' '\n')` and it will break them out onto separate lines.

I maintain `gridjs-vue` by the way.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however on my html end \n is converted to space instead of new line

Answer (score 0):

I got it done this way -

```
colums:[
....
{
name : "Artist",
formatter: (cell) =>{
    return gridjs.html(cell)
},},....]

---- 
server :{
url : '#url....'
then: data => data.result.map(show => [...,
show.Artist.toString().replace(',','<br />') ..]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just getting started with gridjs, its fun for sure.